# How to disable @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type for some(), filter(), forEach()?

Tags: typescript, eslint

How to disable [`@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/explicit-function-return-type.md#require-explicit-return-types-on-functions-and-class-methods-explicit-function-return-type) for `some()`, `filter()`, `forEach()`?

It's very annoying to declare a `boolean` return type for `some()` and `filter()` and `void` for `forEach()` every time.

#### Invalid

```
[2, 5, 8, 1, 4].some(elem => elem > 10)
```

#### Valid

```
[2, 5, 8, 1, 4].some((elem):boolean => elem > 10)
```

I want to be able to use the first pattern (marked "invalid") without getting errors from this rule.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In your `.eslintrc` file you can add the following under `rules`:

```
{
  ...
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
  "rules": {
    ...
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": [
        "error",
        { "allowExpressions": true } 
    ]
  }
}
```

According to the documentation on [allowExpressions](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/explicit-function-return-type.md#allowexpressions), this would allow you to provide inline callbacks to any function without declaring explicit return types.

Comment: It now changed to `"@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "off"`

Comment: @AO19 what do you mean?

Comment: I'm updating this answer to use the new syntax, based on what AO19 commented above.

Answer (score 12):

This is how `.eslintrc` should be configured for rule `@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type`

```
{
  "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "off",
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx"],
      "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
      ...
      "rules": {
        ...
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": [
          "error",
          {
            "allowExpressions": true
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Examples of correct code for this rule with { allowExpressions: true }:

```
node.addEventListener('click', () => {});

node.addEventListener('click', function() {});

const foo = arr.map(i => i * i);
```

More info see documentation for [allowExpressions](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/explicit-function-return-type.md#allowexpressions).

Comment: OMG, after 1 hour of google search and reading documentation I've finally found the solution. Thank you so much! The only thing, `"@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "off"` should be within the `rules` section.

Answer (score 4):

You have to set it as `"off"` in .eslint configuration file:

```json
{
  ...
  "rules": {
    ...
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "off"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": {
      "allowExpressions": true
    }
  },
```