# Why eslint ignored type inference of TypeScript

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

TypeScript can infer the return type of a function and this is very neat in my opinion.

Why then **eslint**, by its default configuration, gives a warning if an explicit return type is not specified for a function?

Answer (score 2):

If your function should always return `number`, but you added a new condition that returns `undefined`, being explicit about the return type lets you decide:

1. The return type should be updated and all callers should handle the `undefined` case.
2. Returning `undefined` was a mistake, and perhaps it was better to throw an error

The point is that explicit return types force the implementer to think about what they intend to return.

Comment: I like your point *"The point is that implicit return types force the implementer to think about what they intend to return"*. Unfortunately there no rule that forces implementers to **to think about what they intend to do with the code**.

Answer (score 0):

Even though TypeScript can infer types, it is often not clear at first sight to the developer what the return type of a function is.

I can only guess the creator thought the same. You can easily change the default behavior, turning it "off" entirely or just for inline callbacks.

[Documentation](https://typescript-eslint-armano.netlify.app/rules/explicit-function-return-type/)

[Another valid question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56907336/how-to-disable-typescript-eslint-explicit-function-return-type-for-some-filt)