# Missing return type on function useAppDispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

**.eslintrc.js**

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: [
    '@react-native-community',
    'standard-with-typescript',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:jest/recommended',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',

    'plugin:import/recommended',

    'plugin:import/typescript',
  ],
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', 'prettier'],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  ignorePatterns: [
    'index.js',
    'metro.config.js',
    'react-native.config.js',
    'reactotron.config.js',
    'babel.config.js',
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    project: './tsconfig.json',
  },
  rules: {
    'prefer-const': 2,
    'no-var': 2,
    'no-new-object': 2,
    'object-shorthand': 2,
    'no-useless-rename': 2,
    'no-prototype-builtins': 2,
    'no-array-constructor': 2,
    'dot-notation': 0,
    semi: 0,
    'padding-line-between-statements': [
      'error',
      { blankLine: 'always', prev: '*', next: 'return' },
      { blankLine: 'always', prev: '*', next: 'break' },
      { blankLine: 'always', prev: '*', next: 'continue' },
      { blankLine: 'always', prev: '*', next: 'function' },
      { blankLine: 'always', prev: '*', next: 'block' },
    ],
    'lines-around-comment': [
      2,
      {
        beforeLineComment: true,
        allowBlockStart: true,
        allowObjectStart: true,
        allowObjectEnd: true,
      },
    ],
    'no-console': 1,
    'no-param-reassign': [
      'error',
      { props: true, ignorePropertyModificationsFor: ['state'] },
    ],

    // @react-native-community config is outdated as we have upgraded typescript
    // ^^ due to the above, all enums started throwing warning
    'no-shadow': 'off',

    // Import rules
    'import/order': [
      'error',
      {
        groups: [
          'builtin',
          'external',
          'internal',
          'parent',
          'sibling',
          'index',
          'object',
          'type',
        ],
        alphabetize: {
          order: 'asc',
        },
        'newlines-between': 'always',
      },
    ],
    'import/no-named-as-default-member': 'off',

    // typescript rules
    '@typescript-eslint/no-shadow': ['error'],
    '@typescript-eslint/strict-boolean-expressions': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': [
      'error',
      {
        allowExpressions: true,
        allowTypedFunctionExpressions: true,
      },
    ],
    '@typescript-eslint/naming-convention': [
      'error',
      {
        selector: 'property',
        format: ['snake_case', 'strictCamelCase', 'UPPER_CASE'],
      },
    ],
  },
  settings: {
    'import/parsers': {
      '@typescript-eslint/parser': ['.ts', '.tsx'],
    },
    'import/resolver': {
      typescript: {
        alwaysTryTypes: true,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

**Store.ts**

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

import usersReducer from '../features/users';

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    users: usersReducer,
  },
});

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;

export default store;
```

**useStore.ts**

```
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import { RootState, AppDispatch } from '../store/index';


export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

`() => useDispatch<AppDispatch>()` expects me to provide a return type as `@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type` is enabled. The return type can be seen by hovering over the constant `useAppDispatch` in VSCode but it would require frequent updates as it's listing the store states.

How can I make the function avoid asking for return type as it's already inferred without disabling the rule? Thank you.

**Packages:**

```
"react-redux": "^7.2.6",
"@types/react-redux": "^7.1.22",
"typescript": "^4.5.4",
```

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56907336/how-to-disable-typescript-eslint-explicit-function-return-type-for-some-filt) helps.

Comment: @NalinRanjan It won't work. I'll share my eslint config.

Comment: You could disable eslint just for that one line. `// eslint-disable-next-line`

Comment: Have you tried the next: export const useAppDispatch = () : AppDispatch => useDispatch<AppDispatch>(); Always should be a way to do it without disabling any rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disable the rule, at least in this line. It is what it is.

Seriously, this rule is harmful.
You do not need to have each and every existing eslint rule active and rules that force annotation with certain types are especially harmful, causing you to remove available type information.

If something is wrong, you will still get a type error, just at usage of the function, not at definition.

There is one place where you need to annotate types and that is in function input positions - because there they cannot be inferred. Everything else is optional. Sometimes it helps readability, sometimes it actively hinders it. Use your mind at that point, don't stick to a fixed rule.

Especially with Redux Toolkit, you get a lot of very specific types and manually annotating those will require you to either duplicate your code in types, or to annotate it in a way that you lose valuable information.

Comment: "especially harmful, causing you to remove available type information" absolutely agree, this is incredibly important to understand. Typescript often infers a lot more from existing types than you could feasibly hardcore your self.

Comment: Agree. quick clarification requested, what do you mean by "annotate types and that is in function input positions". You mean annotate types while passing args to fns?

Comment: When you define a function, you have to add argument types - because there they cannot be inferred and you would end up with `any`. 
`function test(arg: string){ /* ... */ }`
Pretty much everywhere else types can be inferred.

Comment: See also this discussion between TypeScript team members ;)
https://twitter.com/SeaRyanC/status/1243384653785907203